# Erro ao usar o método sendMessage() da classe Handler. "A mensagem não foi postada ou já foi removida"

Tags: android

Estou estudando sobre Threads e Services e sei que para rodar um processo mais longo, como procurar sinal de internet ou fazer download, devo colocá-lo para ser executado em um Background Thread e não no UI (User Interface) Thread. No app abaixo fiz um exemplo de código sendo executado no background e, conforme esse processo progride, há atualizações na barra de progresso, porém quando executo o aplicativo, levo um erro dizendo o seguinte:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.

Abaixo está o código:

```
package com.gabrielm.myapplication;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Handler mHandler;
    Button mButton;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        mHandler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                mProgressBar.setProgress(msg.arg1);
            }
        };

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Message msg = Message.obtain();
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                            msg.arg1 = i;
                            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Procurando na internet por uma possível solução para o problema, descobri que o método `sendMessage(msg)` tem que enviar sempre um novo objeto do tipo `Message` para a fila de mensagens cada vez que eu quero enviar uma nova mensagem. Ou seja, não posso reutilizar o mesmo objeto, tenho que sempre criar um novo cada vez que quero enviar um dado para o `handleMessage(Message msg);`. Então o que eu fiz foi retirar a linha de código `Message msg = Message.obtains();` do lugar onde estava e colocar dentro do bloco `for`, porque assim cada vez que o `for` executa, ele cria um novo objeto do tipo `Message`.

Essa pequena mudança no código fez com o programa funcionasse, porém não tenho certeza se o que eu fiz foi a forma mais correta de realizar o processo. Assim, gostaria de saber se a lógica que desenvolvi aqui está certa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executar códigos em background no Android utilizando Handlers e Threads é uma tarefa muitas vezes complicada e suscetível a erros, por conta disso, foi criada uma classe especial para facilitar a execução de tarefas assíncronas: a [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

A *AsynTask* fornece os seguintes métodos:

1. **onPreExecute** : Método chamado antes que a tarefa de longa duração seja executada. Geralmente é utilizada para preparar e começar a mostrar um progress bar ( ainda vazio ).
2. **doInBackground** : Realiza uma tarefa de longa duração ( acesso ao BD, download de um documento, etc. ).

   **Atenção:** *Dentro deste método não devem ser feitos acessos a elementos da view, caso isso seja feito, você receberá um erro do tipo* **java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"**

   Se você quiser manipular a view, você deve usar os métodos  `onPreExecute()` e `onPostExecute()`

   Porém, se realmente for necessário acessar a view dentro do método `doInBackground()` coloque o método de acesso a view dentro do método `runOnUiThread()` e coloque-o dentro do `doInBackground()`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... parametros) {

       // Realiza tarefa de longa duração ...

       // Acessa a view
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

           public void run() {

               // faça o acesso a view aqui
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. **onProgressUpdate** : Utilizada para atualizar o status da tarefa de longa duração ( *e.g.* incrementar um progress bar). Esse método é chamado toda vez que for feita uma chamada ao método `publishProgress()`
4. **onPostExecute** : Chamado assim que a tarefa de longa duração é concluída. É utilizada para acessar e tratar a variável de retorno da tarefa de longa duração

É importante saber que, como a *AsyncTask* é uma classe abstrata, ela só pode ser estendida, e não instanciada, além disso, por possuir parâmetros genéricos no seu construtor ( `AsyncTask <Params, Progress, Result>` ), ao estender a classe *AsyncTask* você deve fornecer o tipo destes parâmetros genéricos, onde:

- **Params**: É o tipo do parâmetro de entrada do método `doInBackground()`
- **Progress**: É o tipo do parâmetro de entrada do método `onProgressUpdate()`
- **Result**: É o tipo do parâmetro de entrada do método `onPostExecute()`

Assim, para criar uma *AsyncTask* que faça downloads de um arquivo, por exemplo, você poderia fazer:

```
// A classe vai receber um conjuntos de URLs como entrada,
// vai enviar um Integer a cada chamada ao método publishProgress()
// e vai enviar um Integer quando a tarefa for finalizada
private class DownloadArquivos extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Integer> {

    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

     // numero de downloads executados
     int downloads = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < urls.lenght ; i++) {

         downloads += downloadFile(urls[i]);
         // downloadFile() é o seu método de longa duração

         // Atualiza o progresso enviando a porcentagem de arquivos
         // baixados até o momento
         publishProgress( (int) ((i / (float) urls.lenght) * 100) );
     }

     return downloads;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

      // método da sua view que atualiza o progress bar
      setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Int result) {

     // método da sua view que mostra uma mensagem
    // após todos os downloads serem efetuados
     showDialog( result + " arquivos baixados com sucesso!" );
 }
 }
```

**Obs.:** Código retirado e adaptado de: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Sim, concordo. A classe abstrata AsyncTask é a mais recomendada para esse tipo de processo que utiliza UI Thread e Background Thread, porém o que estava com dúvida era sobre a classe Handler. Uma dúvida que me surgiu é que com o Handler eu posso manusear um processo que usa dois Threads quaisquer, seja UI Thread e um Background Thread ou dois em Background. Já o AsyncTask é só para um Background Thread e UI Thread. Isso está correto ou tem como trabalhar com dois Threads quaisquer  usando o AsyncTask?

Comment: Outra coisa, pesquisando mais sobre o assunto, percebi que no método doInBackground() eu não preciso criar um Thread, por que o código dentro desse método já está sendo executado no segundo plano. Isso era algo que estava fazendo errado, porém estava funcionando. Oque eu estava fazendo era criar um Thread dentro do doInBackground(), o que é desnecessário.

Comment: @GabrielM.Linassi é possível sim executar duas threads em paralelo e na background task, mas para isso vc vai precisar utilizar o método `executeOnExecutor()` ( dê uma olhada na [documentação oficial](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor) ). Quanto a segunda pergunta: Sim, o doInBackground já é executado em background ( como diz o nome :D ) , portanto você pode executar diretamente seu método dentro dele sem criar uma thread nova

Answer (score 2):

Gabriel, sua pesquisa lhe trouxe informações corretas. Não é possível enviar o mesmo objeto Message várias vezes, então, temos sempre que criar uma nova instância. Ou melhor, ao invés de criarmos uma instância usando `new Message()`, podemos usar `Message.obtain()` que retornará uma instância de Message vinda de um pool de objetos reciclados, o que é menos custoso que a primeira opção.

> While the constructor of Message is public, the best way to get one of
>   these is to call Message.obtain() or one of the
>   Handler.obtainMessage() methods, which will pull them from a pool of
>   recycled objects.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, é bom saber que estou no caminho certo. Demorei algumas horas para entender bem isso, mas acho que agora finalmente consegui diluir esse conteúdo. A propósito, eu estava com dúvida se deveria usar Message msg = Message.obtains() ou Message msg = new Message(), mas agora entedi que o melhor é o Message.obtains(), já que ele está reutilizando um objeto reciclado e não criando um novo. Enfim, obrigado por sua resposta, foi de grande ajuda.